# Варианты вопросов-ответов в текстовой игре

Tags: java, проектирование, разработка-игр

Многие, наверное, играли в игру "Космические рейнджеры", а кто играл - тот, наверное, знает что там из себя представляет тюрьма.

 Я сейчас пытаюсь разработать похожую квестовую игру на Java, но столкнулся с проблемой организации вопросов-ответов. Имеется в виду, как можно организовать всю эту систему? 
Например, у меня есть 1 JLabel, который из себя представляет основной текст (это описание местоположения, объектов вокруг, разговоры с нпс и т.д.) и 3 кнопки JButton (до 3 вариантов ответа на каждую из ситуаций соответственно) 

 Значит, если вас спрашиваю (в лейбле) как вас зовут, вы можете ответить: Дима, Катя или Сёма. И в зависимости от того, что вы ответите, вам зададут какие-нибудь ещё вопросы.

 Как это возможно реализовать в Java, имея класс с 3 кнопками и лейбл? (if-else и создание нового окна по нажатию на кнопку - не подходит)

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, Вы зря делаете упор на интерфейс (кнопки, метки и так далее). Создайте систему классов с вопросами, которые можно представить в виде дерева: значение узла - текст вопроса, дочерние ветви - варианты ответов, которые ведут к другим вопросам или действиям. После того, как такие классы и дерево будет создано, и Вы сможете программно его обходить (отвечать на вопросы), тогда можно делать интерфейс.

Comment: Делал. Получилось, можно сказать, иерархическое дерево (подобное иерархической модели данных)
Дело в том, что я не знаю, каким способом это можно реализовать. Тут даже дело не столько в интерфейсе, чем в том, как в том, как это вообще делается, пусть даже будет без интерфейса совсем.